# Cómo obtener la fecha de registros de una tabla que no tiene campo para guardarla

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, date, timestamp

Tengo una tabla de la que necesito obtener la fecha de creación o modificación de cada registro. El dilema es que la tabla no tiene un campo que guarde el *timestamp* de la fecha de creación o el cambio.

¿Como puedo hacer para extraerla?

Comment: ¿La base ya existe y el evento ya sucedió? o ¿es para diseñar una base de datos que está por recibir inserts y la pregunta es para obtener esos timestamps de otro lado que no sea de la tabla? (si es lo primero ambas respuestas son correctas, si es lo segundo se puede crear una tabla de timestamps con la misma pk que la tabla)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta corta es que **no se puede hacer eso**.  Si quieres saber cual es la fecha de creación y/o modificación de un registro, es tu responsabilidad mantener esa información agregándole columnas a la tabla para ese fin. No sucede de forma automática.

Con esto dicho, en versiones más recientes de PostgreSQL, hay forma de activar una configuración que te permite obtener el *commit timestamp* de un registro (Referencia: [Commit timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP)). Pero aun si usaras esto:

- Solo obtendrías una aproximación de la fecha en que se modificó el registro la última vez
- Solo obtendrías la fecha de la última vez que se modificó el registro. No tendrías la fecha de creación.
- La información solo está disponible por un tiempo limitado.

Para más información sobre tu pregunta y las opciones disponibles, puedes leer esta excelente respuesta a la pregunta [Getting last modification date of a PostgreSQL database table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58246/72418).

Answer (score 0):

Esto es posible únicamente si estás guardando el log de TODOS tus queries, podrías entonces usar algo como grep en Linux para buscar la transacción:

```
grep 'registro' archivoDeLog
```

Por lo menos en mi país hay reglas que te obligan a guardar el log de tus bases de datos en el caso del sector financiero así loggear todos los queries no es descabellado pero definitivamente es más costoso que agregar un campo timestamp a la tabla.